# Problems with default image sizes in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

:)

Recently I changed the default LARGE size from 960px width to 1280px width.
When I upload the image, WP creates the 1280px image, BUT when I insert it into the post, it still uses the 960px settings, even with the 1280 image.

It's like:

```
<img src="image-1280x853.jpg" alt="" width="960" height="640" class="aligncenter size-large" />
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're asking two questions - you should split them.

Comment: Normally you should get new setting after editing the functions.php for image size. So please try something like save the permalink again, logout and login, and clear all cache. I think, your problem will be solved.